# How to Install Scapy_http for python 3 windows

Tags: python, scapy

I can't seem to install `scapy_http` on my windows machine. I have installed `scapy-http` (Please note the difference), but it doesn't work.

I always get this error when trying to install `scapy_http`:

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\user\desktop\spoofer\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-osyn3x82\\meinheld\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-osyn3x82\\meinheld\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-u_2h8iz_'
     cwd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-osyn3x82\meinheld\
Complete output (2 lines):
Are you really running a posix compliant OS ?
Be posix compliant is mandatory
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

how can I install it with no issues?.

Answer (score 0):

Scapy 2.4.3+ includes scapy-http so there's no need to install it.
See the disclaimer on `scapy-http`'s github page: https://github.com/invernizzi/scapy-http

> OBSOLETE!
>
> Scapy 2.4.3+ has native support for HTTP. It has the same syntax as this package (isn't that nice), plus it packs more features!
>
> Please consider this package as obsolete - long live Scapy!